# Umbraco 8: SetValue has some invalid arguments - Saving new image to media C#

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco8

**Q) How can I fix the method call below so it's got valid arguments?**

**Background to problem:**

Based on [this post here...](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/99666-upload-image-to-media-folder) - I'm trying to download an image from a URL (hard-coded below for brevity), then save it to the media folder.

**I get an error:**

```
The best overloaded method match for 'Umbraco.Core.Models.ContentBase.SetValue(string, object, string, string)' has some invalid arguments
```

**Imports:**

```
using Umbraco.Web.WebApi;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using Umbraco.Core;
```

**Method detail:**

```
var imageSrc = "https://images.isbndb.com/covers/81/38/9781538748138.jpg";

try 
{
    var mediaSvc = Services.MediaService;
    var mediaExtension = Path.GetExtension(imageSrc);
    var imageName = Guid.NewGuid() + mediaExtension;

    var image = DownloadImageFromUrl(imageSrc);

    const string rootPath = "~\\media";
    var fileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(rootPath, imageName));
    image.Save(fileName);

    dynamic newImage = null;

    // -1 is the root folderID, i.e. Media.  All images will be saved under Media in Umbraco
    newImage = mediaSvc.CreateMedia(imageName, -1, "Image");

    var buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\media\\" + imageName));

    newImage.SetValue(Services.ContentTypeBaseServices, "umbracoFile", imageName, new MemoryStream(buffer));
    mediaSvc.Save(newImage);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\media\\" + imageName)))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\media\\" + imageName));
    }

    return newImage.Id;
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    return ex;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this by changing the lines

```
dynamic newImage = null;
newImage = mediaSvc.CreateMedia(imageName, -1, "Image");
```

to:

```
var newImage = mediaSvc.CreateMedia(imageName, -1, "Image");
```

So it must be the `dynamic` keyword that was causing the method to match to the wrong signature, not the extension method.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to do the saving in ~/media yourself at all. That path is set by Umbraco and can be overridden by custom providers. So leave that part to the MediaService.

Also, when you are saving a Media item you shouldn't (you can't) give it a path, only a file name, which is what I expect is causing you problems as well.

Have you looked at the documentation here? https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Management/Services/MediaService/